# External nuget has DefaultAzureCredential() for auth token creation, which fails while debugging in local visual studio

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, defaultazurecredential

My Project is using a nuget which implementing auth token validation using `DefaultAzureCredential()` based SecretClient creation for reading azure keyvault.

Due to DefaultAzureCredential follows following order for auth, my code gives `mangedIdentity expection` while running code in visualStudio.
What shall be done to enable local debugging of code smoothly, can we change this order or can we change the code for debug mode in external nuget?

> EnvironmentCredential
>
> WorkloadIdentityCredential
>
> ManagedIdentityCredential
>
> AzureDeveloperCliCredential
>
> SharedTokenCacheCredential
>
> VisualStudioCredential
>
> VisualStudioCodeCredential
>
> AzureCliCredential
>
> AzurePowerShellCredential
>
> InteractiveBrowserCredential

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet

Exception details: (comes while debugging on local)
Message:

```
Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException : ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Method not found: '!0 Microsoft.Identity.Client.AbstractApplicationBuilder`1.WithInstanceDiscovery(Boolean)'.
See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/managedidentitycredential/troubleshoot
---- System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: '!0 Microsoft.Identity.Client.AbstractApplicationBuilder`1.WithInstanceDiscovery(Boolean)'.
```

Comment: You can't use your own identity for auth?

Comment: Could you please share your code. What is the .NET version you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

> enable local debugging of code smoothly

Thanks @[christothes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity#authenticating-via-visual-studio) for the steps.

To authenticate with Visual Studio credentials, we need to check the `Azure credentials` in VS.

- Same account has to be configured where your Azure Subscription is active.

[image]

- If you have multiple accounts configured then Apply filter and select the correct tenant and domain.

[image]

- Make sure you have installed the latest version of `Azure.Identity` and `Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets`.

```cs
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I have created an `ASP.NET Core` Application and trying to retrieve secrets from `Azure Key Vault`.

In `appsettings.json`, add the `KeyVaultURL`.

```cs
  "KeyVaultURL": "https://harshiithakv.vault.azure.net/"
```

With the below code Iam able to retrieve the secret without any issues.
`Program.cs` :

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var keyVaultURL = builder.Configuration["KeyVaultURL"];
var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultURL), new DefaultAzureCredential());
var KVSecret = secretClient.GetSecret("KVSecret").Value;
Console.WriteLine(KVSecret.Value);

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");  
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run();
```

***Output:***

[image]

> can we change this order or can we change the code for debug mode in external nuget?

As suggested by [cognophile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75096380), instead of changing the order try to enable only the authentication which you want to try and check once.